# jquery masonry: nth-child() adds unneeded margin to child nodes

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I am trying to use the awesome jquery masonry plugin -> http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/

The plugin works just fine, however I have problems creating a layout where I use an nth-child() selector to get rid of a margin-right on every third element.

```
#footerwidgets li.widget {
    margin: 0px 24px 24px 0px;
    width:340px;
}

#footerwidgets li.widget:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

Since my container for this widget is exactly 1068px wide, three widgets fit in perfectly (because the last widget has no right margin).

When I try to use the jquery masonry plugin, this behaviour gets ignored! Only two columns fit in. (The plugin works, so all widgets get floated in masonry style.) When I inspect the elements, every third element has a right margin of 24px as well. So nth-child is ignored.

Any way to make that working?

Comment: What browser did you test this in? The `nth-child` selector is CSS 3, so the support is still a bit limited. Internet Explorer doesn't support it until version 9.

Comment: I'm using chrome and or safari

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With jQuery, remove margins and use [Masonry's gutterWidth option](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/gutters.html) in its place.

CSS:

```
#footerwidgets li.widget.masonry-brick { margin: 0; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('#footerwidgets').masonry({
  gutterWidth: 24
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Masonry does not work well with variable-sized margins. You have three columns and a container of 528px. Your best bet is to go with three columns of 176px. Each columns would have a margin of, say 12px and a width of 152px.

If you want your total width minus left and right margins to be 528px, then expand the container to 544px (528px + 2 x 12px) and your columns' width to 160.

Comment: sry, that comma is not the problem, that' just a little mistake that happened with posting this question... the problem is that i want three widgets to fit horizontally into my #wrapper div (1068px wide). every widget is 340px wide and has a margin-right of 24px. Every third widget has its right margin set to 0; that means 340+24+340+24+340 = 1068. This works fine when I don't use masonry. However when I use masonry all widgets have a 24px right margin and so every third element is floated left as well -> so only two columns of widgets fit into my wrapper.

Comment: and yes, you understood me correctly. my third widget is floated left.However I want it to float right to the top besides the other two widgets.

Comment: Can you post a link to your HTML it would help me better answer your question. Use something like pastebin

Comment: this is my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DfpXe/ uncomment the javascript line and see. Actually three columns would fit in, however with masonry only two fit in.